# Running Pig NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera

I'm trying to get pig running on my machine but whenever I try to start pig I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:642)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
```

This happens whenever I run `pig` or when I try to execute scripts that should work.

I'm not completely certain what is going on but it looks like I'm likely not including some of the hadoop jars correctly. Has anyone seen a similar issue or know how to include the needed jars?

For reference I'm using Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.4.9 and Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.9 and I have these environment variables set:

```
PIG_HOME=/Users/username/cdh5/pig-0.12.0-cdh5.4.9
PIG_CLASSPATH=/etc/hadoop/conf:/Users/username/cdh5/hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.4.9/*:/Users/username/cdh5/hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.4.9/lib/*
```

Do I need to find the hadoop jars and add those to my path or is there something else I should check.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being because I was setting CDH_MR2_HOME incorrectly and therefore pig could not find some of the jars it needed.